# How can I use git difftool on a patch file?

Tags: git, patch, vimdiff

As the opening title suggests, I am trying to produce a side-by-side diff using `git difftool`. I am in an environment s.t. `vimdiff` is the only available tool on these computers and am using CLI commands to do code reviews.

If I have the head/origin (that may be desynced/unable to do `git apply`), **how would I create a side-by-side diff when I have a patch file** (produced via `git diff patch-a patch-b > patch-file.patch`)?

Obviously, the ideal scenario would be `git apply myPatch.patch`, `git difftool -y origin-hash patch-hash`, but this does not always work.

Comment: just let me point out that patch files are not exclusive for git - they are just the output of diff, which is used in VCS much older than git, such as svn, cvs, rcs, sccs, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking of developing a tool that just makes this.

I found out there is at least already one that makes it. Beware it is not free software, but perhaps you may be able to use it.

It is called *beyond compare*. I use it on windows.

If you have a patch file, in the context menu you shall use *open with*, then select *beyond compare* (assuming you have installed it and you have no licensing issues).